# Is not a function error getting

Tags: javascript

```
var newSalary = function(){
    var salary = 30000;
    function update (amount){
        salary += amount;
    }
    return {
        hike: function(){
            update (5000);
        },
        lower: function(){
            update (-5000);
        },
        current: function(){
            return salary;
        }
    }
}

console.log('current salary::'+newSalary.current());
```

Getting:

> *`newSalary.current` is not a function.*

What's wrong in the code?

Comment: is this homework?

Comment: here's a hint : you defined a function that returns an object, but you do not have an *instance* of that object.

Comment: thanks for the answer it's working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `newSalary` function to get object having definition of `current` function:

```
console.log('current salary::' + newSalary().current());
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `newSalary` as a **function**, with parantheses `()`:

```
console.log('current salary::' + newSalary().current());
                                          ▲
```

Here's a working snippet:

```js
var newSalary = function(){
    var salary = 30000;
    function update (amount){
        salary += amount;
    }
    return {
        hike: function(){
            update (5000);
        },
        lower: function(){
            update (-5000);
        },
        current: function(){
            return salary;
        }
    }
}

console.log('current salary::' + newSalary().current());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
console.log('current salary::'+newSalary().current());
```

Since newSalary is a function you have to add the () to call it.

Answer (score 0):

You need create instance of object

`var salary = new newSalary();
salary.current();`

Answer (score 0):

Add a "return salary" to both the hike and lower functions :

```
var newSalary = function(){
    var salary = 30000;
    function update (amount){
        salary += amount;
    }
    return {
        hike: function(){
            update (5000);
            return salary;
        },
        lower: function(){
            update (-5000);
            return salary;
        },
        current: function(){
            return salary;
        }
    }
}
```

You can then call them by using either `newSalary().hike();` or `newSalary().lower();`